# Що таке "мачка"?

Tags: значення-слів

Цікавить, що означає слово "мачка".

Зустрів його в виразі: "Мачку засвітити", який означає "дати ляпаса". Але не розумію чи "мачка" - це ляпас, чи це щось інше.

Не знайшов такого слова в СУМі, а в [Русинсько-українському словнику](http://lang.slovopedia.org.ua/10/53404/117431.html) знайшов, що "**мачка** - мацур" - це те саме що "**кішка** - кіт". Але в такому випадку, я не розумію до чого там слово "засвітити".

Comment: а може це дати ляпаса, так, що мочка вуха почервоніла?

Comment: Теж думав про сього спочатку і хотів розвинути, однак мосьпан Франко, чи ьа так зустрів, вжив сеь вираз в лапках, а словники подаьуть ьак «злодіьськиь говір». Сьебто вже не дуже підходить.

Comment: До речи, коли подумати, то «мосвозлодіьськиь говір» теж маье слово «засьвітити» в ьакостьи «зробити шчось видне», наприклад «засвєтіть фінґал», тому може і мочка, але чому саме вона? Але скоріш сье шчось сучасніше і пішло від шчось такого штибу.

Comment: Я б сказав, що _мачка_ тут — скорочене від _макітра_, тобто «голова». Але це суто інтуїтивно, тому може бути (й, імовірніше за все, є) дуже помилково.

Answer (score 4):

Зустрів такиь вираз в творі пана Франка

> [«Не вільно в казні тютюну курити…»](https://www.i-franko.name/uk/Verses/ZVershynINyzyn/TjuremniSonety/NeVilnoVKazni.html)
>
> Не вільно в казні тютюну курити,
>   Книжок читати, ні свічок світити,
>   Не вільно в візитирку говорити,
>   В вікно глядіти, грішми що платити.
>
> Папір і олівець при собі мати –
>   Для арештанта се тяжка провина;
>   Ножа теж казня мати не повинна,
>   Хліб нігтями й зубами треба рвати.
>
> А ключник, стражник може в кождій хвили
>   Перетрясти все в казні, обшукати
>   Вас до сорочки, **«мачку засвітити»**,
>
> І язиком, як хоче, вас честити,
>   За кару вас в «густую» казню дати,
>   Де б вас кумпани обкрадали й били.

Там є підказка, котра сумісна з вашою — вираз значить **дати ляпаса**. Про *мачку* нїц. [Грінченко](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/27915-machka.html) вказує окрім *кішки* також на:

> 2) = **баґа**. Шух. І. 277. Cм. **омачка**.

Слово *баґа* [мадярського похоџеня](http://history.org.ua/LiberUA/EtSlUkrM_1982/EtSlUkrM_1982.pdf#page=108) — [*bagó*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bag%C3%B3) — і значить [**недогарки з люльки**](http://litopys.org.ua/rizne/etno2.htm), шчо за смислом лїпше, як на мене, підходить, бо: близьке до теми вязницї, а також цӧго можна [сьвітити](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=32228&page=1042), до того ж є иншиь [приклад](http://sum.in.ua/s/nedogharok) в прямому значінї:

> *Вигоріла свічка, Леон засвітив недогарок, але і той скоро кінчився*.

Comment: Гадаю, що ви можете бути праві. Однак, можливо, воно й справді походить від слова "мочка" як пишуть у коментарях...

Answer (score 2):

Мачка - різдвяна страва поширена у лемків та надсянців, гриби у густому білому соусі. Як правило, її споживають не як окрему страву, а вмачають в неї вареники або хліб.

В [ЯК УКРАЇНЦІ З НАДСЯННЯ СВЯТВЕЧЕРЯЛИ](http://risu.org.ua/ua/index/exclusive/holidays_and_customs/69773) пишуть:

> Варили і грибну підливу («губи», «мачку», «мачанку з грибами»)

Фактично, це підлива. Зустрічаються рецепти мачки з птиці чи навіть оселедця.

Можна припустити, що вираз "мачку засвітити" в контексті ляпаса може бути змістовно споріднений до "заюшити", цебто зацідити так, щоб аж потекло. Але це не точно.

Comment: І шчо значе вираз «засьвітити мачку»?

Comment: В книзі «УКРАЇНСЬКІ НАЗВИ З КУХОВАРСТВА Й ХАРЧУВАННЯ» на сторінці 58 знайшов таке ***мачка** (лем.) - різдвяна страва з
оселедця.*

Comment: @bytebuster питання було "що означає слово "мачка"". 
Зрозуміло що у контексті фразеологізмів слова можуть мати дещо інше значення, наприклад "дати ляща" - це не про рибу.
Щодо джерела, то для мене моя бабця та її різдвяна вечеря є джерелом достатньо поважним. Втім, мушу уточнити, що бабця таки була не з самої Лемківщини, а з Надсяння, і наведене далі джерело підтверджує саме такий варіант.
Тут https://risu.org.ua/ua/index/exclusive/holidays_and_customs/69773/ 
пишуть, що "Варили і грибну підливу («губи», «мачку», «мачанку з грибами»)"

Підсумовуючи, скажу що "мачка" - це підлива.

Comment: @manuna, оце чудове пояснення з вашого коментаря має бути частиною відповіді. Разом із посиланням. І хоча RISU не є науковим джерелом, воно може використовуватися як приклад використання у пресі. Окремо від того, варто знайти докази припущення щодо «змістовно споріднений до "заюшити"» і також додати їх до відповіді.

Comment: @bytebuster на те воно і припущення, бо поки не має підтвердження. Але якщо хтось його прочитає і зможе аргументувати його достовірність, то за бажання додасть коментар.

Comment: @manuna у тім-то й справа. Stack Exchange — це не discussion board. Відповіді мають ґрунтуватися на фактичних матеріалах і поважних джерелах, а не на особистій думці користувачів. Припущення чудово годяться на мовних форумах і блоґах. Але не годяться тут. Просто такий формат цього сайту. Див., напр., [тут](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/191/8)